# Does nix always create virtual environment deterministically

Tags: nix

```
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable;
    flake-utils.url = github:numtide/flake-utils;
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      in
      {

        devShells.default = with pkgs; mkShell {
          packages = [ cargo rustup rustc rust-analyzer rustfmt cmake ];
          RUST_SRC_PATH = rustPlatform.rustLibSrc;
        };
      }
    );
}
```

This is a flake.nix necessary to set a virtual environment with rust thanks to the command

```
    nix develop -i
```

the i say only the elements defined in the flake are used. No program other than the program defined in the virtual environment can be used.

```
     rustup toolchain list
> 1.70  //OK

    rustup toolchain install 1.69
    rustup default 1.69
    rustc --version
 > rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)   // OK
```

Now I quit the virtual environment

```
  exit
```

Then I reopen it.

```
    rustc --version
> 1.69
```

It means that the version of rust has been stored somewhere. It means that nix isn´t deterministic. The same flake can produce different environment.
Is that a bug or are there others things that I should know.

Comment: I'm not sure how flakes works, but I think the provided flake.nix is not exactly 'pure' as you have not pinned the commit that github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable references. In addition just because 10 + 10 = 20 does not mean 20 is being stored somewhere and hence not deterministic?

Comment: Hello @ChrisStryczynski . I m not sure how flakes works too. What I will say is possibly wrong. After running the flake.nix a flake.lock is created, there is description of you exactly use. If somebody reuse your flake.nix and flake.lock. That should be deterministic.

https://www.tweag.io/blog/2020-05-25-flakes/ and ctrl F As a result, building dwarffs will always produce the same result

Comment: It's guaranteed that the build will use the same steps and have access to the same inputs (if you're on a platform where Nix supports sandboxing). It's not _quite_ guaranteed that it'll have the same results even from the same inputs, because even though a sandboxed build can't get to, say, undeclared network assets, it can still access the system clock.

Comment: _However_, just because the devshell is _built_ with deterministic processes doesn't mean _using_ it is hermetic unless you go out of your way to make it so.

Comment: This is to say -- yes, the _creation_ of the environment is approximately deterministic, but that doesn't mean the _use_ of the environment is hermetic.

Comment: BTW, if you want a deterministically built runtime environment, Nix _does_ support creating virtual machine images -- that's how the test framework it ships with works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Building* Nix components (on systems where this is both supported and enabled) happens in a network-free, limited-filesystem-access sandbox where only declared dependencies are available. (It's still not a 100% guarantee of identical output every time because there's pollution from the outside world via things like the system clock, various random number generators, timing differences and load differences changing when process task switches take place, etc etc).

`nix develop` does two things: First, it *builds* a devshell and its dependencies (where the build steps happen in the sandbox); then it starts an interactive shell process in the user's regular environment. **This latter step, of interactively using a devshell, does not take place in this sandbox. No documentation I'm aware of claims otherwise.**

- When `-i` is passed, `$HOME` isn't exposed (usually folks using `-i`/`--ignore-env` also use `--keep HOME` to override this), but if a program figures it out (f/e, with an account lookup), it's perfectly capable of caching content under `HOME/.cache/rustup` or any similar location.
- If you want each devshell invocation to have a new and different HOME directory, it's your job to do this yourself -- which you *can* do easily; `mkdir "$TMPDIR"/home && HOME=$TMPDIR/home` will do nicely, since starting `nix develop` creates a new and unique `TMPDIR`.